# BIOS not showing Windows Boot Manager as bootable device after Ubuntu Install on secondary SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Having made the unfortunate mistake of thinking I was competent enough to configure a dual boot system with an HDD and a new Samsung SSD, I've encountered an issue. I installed Ubuntu on my new SSD with the primary drive unplugged so as to avoid an accidental overwrite of my HDD Windows drive. After installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, whenever I try and select a boot device in BIOS all that is shown is Ubuntu (which boots fine), but I don't see a Windows Boot Loader, instead I see this: WDC WD10EZEX-60Z as a bootable device. Once I select it, the splash page with the Windows load animation just hangs. My `fdisk -l` output shows as follows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-60Z
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D1F1C1E0-64FF-4AA7-9469-C0083D80FD24

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2      206848     468991     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      468992 1597837294 1597368303 761.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1597837312 1920618495  322781184 153.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1920620544 1921722367    1101824   538M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  1921722368 1953513471   31791104  15.2G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 381AE92F-414A-4108-B2D5-8CCA9049C7B3

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem
```

This is very confusing to me as Ubuntu can tell I my HDD has a Windows file system. Any guidance for this foolish novice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't mention what Ubuntu product, and what release of that product you're using, but have you tried `sudo update-grub` to ask the grub boot loader to update itself. If the windows drive was removed; it won't have been found when installed, and with it now connected; I'd expect most Ubuntu product/releases to detect it now that it's reconnected.   *If you change bios firmware settings when re-enabling the ssd, you may need to re-install grub (`grub-install`) as well if drive boot order has changed due to firmware change; though if Ubuntu boots now this may not be necessary*

Comment: Were both Windows & Ubuntu installed using the same firmware mode (eg. *legacy/CSM*, uEFI, or Secure-uEFI? as problems can be expected if they were installed in different modes)

Comment: The update-grub should put Windows into the grub menu, but you can always boot an UEFI Windows via the EFI boot menu (some key at power-up to let you select device/os to boot).

Comment: If both are UEFI, which it looks like since you have ESP - efi system partition and gpt partitioning, then `sudo update-grub` should work if Windows fast start up/hibernation and bitlocker are off. Otherwise os-prober cannot see the Windows install. Note that Windows updates may turn fast start up back on or may update UEFI resetting many UEFI settings back to defaults. Some systems need few, if any UEFI settings changed and others need a lot. One system I have to keep a list of 7 UEFI settings changes & the other just works as long as bitlocker & fast startup are off.